# Assigning a Cell Number Using A Variable (Not Cell Value)

Tags: excel, vba

I need to locate a given cell number (such as C100) based on values of relative cells on several workbooks containing variable data. Once I've defined two such cell numbers- a range- I will need the average of the values contained in those cells.

Here is the set up, which DOES function properly.

```
'   Perform "FIND" function for the first case of "LOCAL PEAK". Note: Since column D is composed of the above formula, the
'   find function only recognizes the VALUES in column E
    Set found = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="LOCAL PEAK", After:=[e1], LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True)

' Assign the row number associated with the first instance of "LOCAL PEAK" to the variable "StaticRow"
    If Not found Is Nothing Then StaticRow = found.Row

' Assign the value in the cell of the force column associated with the first instance of "LOCAL PEAK" to the variable "SForce"
    SForce = Cells(StaticRow, 3).Value

' Assign the value in the cell of the position column associated with the first instance of "LOCAL PEAK" to the variable "InitialPos"
    InitialPos = Cells(StaticRow, 2).Value

' Assign the rows for Kinetic Friction calculation
    KineticRowA = StaticRow + 60
    KineticRowB = StaticRow + 300
```

Moving on to what I've tried that doesn't work:

```
    CellA = Cells(KineticRowA, 3)
    CellB = Cells(KineticRowB, 3)

KForce = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(CellA, CellB))
```

The above method assigns VALUES to the variables CellA and CellB, instead of the cell position.

This next one just flat-out doesn't work :)

```
KForce = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("CKineticRowA:CKineticRowB"))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Missing `Set` if you're assigning a value to a Range variable:

```
Dim CellA As Range, CellB As Range, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set CellA = ws.Cells(KineticRowA, 3)
Set CellB = ws.Cells(KineticRowB, 3)

KForce = WorksheetFunction.Average(ws.Range(CellA, CellB))
```